# Distinguish rules with common prefix

Tags: parsing, bison

I am facing a problem with rules that with long look ahead

Take as an example a parser that consumes integer or fractions, also the fractions have no `GAP`s in the numerator (however it may have `GAP`s between the numerator and the `SLASH`)

The regular expression `[0-9_ ]*?([0-9]+\/[0-9_ ]+)|[0-9_ ]+` describes the valid inputs
you can check some examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/bp6klt/1).

Here is one way to write it

```txt
Value: Integer | Fraction;
Fraction: IntegerTokenStar DigitPlus GapStar SLASH IntegerToken
DigitPlus: DIGIT DigitPlus | DIGIT
GapStar: GAP GapStar | %empty
Integer: IntegerTokenPlus
IntegerToken: DIGIT | GAP
IntegerTokenStar: IntegerToken IntegerTokenStar | %empty
IntegerTokenPlus: IntegerToken IntegerTokenPlus | IntegerToken
```

But it will fail to parse even an example like `0 0/0`, the IntegerTokenStar will consume as much as it can, then trying to parse the numerator there is no digit available, trying to continue with integer is not possible because it has a '/'.

How to write this in a conceptually clear way and that we can produce a valid parser.

#### Examples

A few strings and the expected (i)nteger part, (n)umerator, (d)enominator.

```txt
1_1_ 1___/1_1 -> fraction {i:"1_1_ ",n:"1___", d:"1_1"}
1_1_ 1___1_1 -> integer {i:"1_1_ 1___1_1",n:"", d:""}
1_1_1___/1_1 -> fraction {i:"",n:"1_1_1___",d:"1_1"}
```

#### frac.y

```
%define parse.error verbose
%locations
%{
void yyerror(const char* s);
extern int yylex();
extern int yylineno;
extern int yycolumn;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
%}


%token DIGIT SLASH GAP NEWLINE

%start File

%%
File: Value | Value NEWLINE File
Value: Integer | Fraction;

Fraction: IntegerTokenStar DigitPlus SLASH IntegerToken
DigitPlus: DIGIT DigitPlus | DIGIT
Integer: IntegerTokenPlus
IntegerToken: DIGIT | GAP
IntegerTokenStar: IntegerToken IntegerTokenStar | %empty
IntegerTokenPlus: IntegerToken IntegerTokenPlus | IntegerToken

%%


int main(){
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

void yyerror(const char* s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Line %d: %s\n", yylineno, s);
    exit(1);
}
```

#### frac.l

```
%option noyywrap yylineno

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "frac.tab.h"
#define YY_DECL int yylex()

int yycolumn = 1;

#define YY_USER_ACTION yylloc.first_line = yylloc.last_line = yylineno; \
    yylloc.first_column = yycolumn; yylloc.last_column = yycolumn + yyleng - 1; \
    yycolumn = yytext[0] == '\n' ? 1: yycolumn + yyleng;

%}


%%
[\n] {return NEWLINE;}
[_ ] {return GAP;}
[0-9] {return DIGIT;}
"/" {return SLASH;}

%%
```

#### Makefile

```
frac: frac.yy.c frac.tab.c
    gcc frac.tab.c frac.yy.c -o frac
frac.yy.c: frac.l
    flex -o frac.yy.c frac.l
frac.tab.c frac.tab.h: frac.y
    bison -d frac.y
```

Comment: What is your goal, exactly? Why are you using bison to do something which would normally be done in a lexical analyser?

Comment: I want to take the sub parts separately, each digit and each gap in a node.

Comment: Neither that rather imprecise statement nor your example demonstrates a reason to not recognise a sequence of digits in your lexer.

Comment: That's because in my real problem I have to handle different digit differently, you could think of each digit as an instruction instead of the number itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that you've split digit sequences with gaps and digit sequences without gaps into two independent rules, which means you need to decide which you're going to match first, which requires (possibly unbounded) lookahead to decide which to match.

The solution is generally to match tokens "bottom up" -- single rule for each thing independent of context, and build up lookahead-dependent things from that.  In you case, that means building up `IntegerToken` from `DigitStar` rather than from `DIGIT` directly -- an input of digits will be recognized as a `DigitStar` and only when you get to the end of it (and see the non-digit) do you need to decide what it is.

The problem is that the obvious fix for your grammar (changing `IntegerToken: DIGIT | GAP` to `DigitStar | GAP`) doesn't work because it makes `IntegerTokenStar` (and -`Plus`) ambigous as any sequence of 2 or more digits might be any number of `DigitStar` tokens.  So you need to rewrite this to make sure you can't have two consecutive `DigitStar` tokens, which turns out to be quite tricky.  Your really need to rethink things "bottom up" -- the input is a sequence of alternating numbers (1+ digits each) and gaps (1+ spaces), with an optional single `/` that can appear directly between two numbers (no gaps) or a number and a gap (no gap before the `/`).  So you get rules that look more like:

```
File: Value | Value NEWLINE File
Value: OptGap Integer OptGap | Fraction ;

Fraction: OptGap Integer GapPlus DigitPlus SLASH OptGap Integer OptGap
        | OptGap DigitPlus SLASH OptGap Integer OptGap
DigitPlus: DIGIT DigitPlus | DIGIT
GapPlus: GAP GapPlus | GAP
OptGap: %empty | GapPlus
Integer: Integer GapPlus DigitPlus | DigitPlus
```

This does the trick, but is needlessly complex as it recognizes 'number' and 'gap'<sup>1</sup> tokens in the grammar rather than the lexer.  There's also the odd corner case of disallowing a gap between the numerator and the `/` in a fraction -- without that we could just ignore spaces (gaps) in the lexer and make things much simpler:

```
File: Value | Value NEWLINE File
Value: Integer | Fraction ;
Fraction: Integer NUMBER SLASH Integer | NUMBER SLASH Integer
Integer: Integer NUMBER | NUMBER
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Side note -- your lexer seems to disagree with your examples as it treats `_` as a GAP token rather than a DIGIT token.
But then your examples don't match your regex -- having a `_` immediately before a `/` will not match</sub>

Comment: Thank you @Chris this points on the right direction, sorry for the confusion on the question. About the possibly unbounded lookahead, I am trying to translate from a PEG.js parser, that does provide unbounded lookahead.

Comment: Would you mind to update your first example to accept gaps before the slash, and give the definition you would use for NUMBER in the second? I did with `[0-9]+[ _]*` for number ` [ _]+` for GAP, and I added an alternative GAP NUMBER to the Integer rule. I will post a follow up question about how to handle this on the lexer.

Comment: I would use `[0-9_]*` for `NUMBER` -- this will match strings of just `_` which you might consider not a number.  Another possibility is `[0-9][0-9_]*` as perhaps things that start with `_` should be identifiers rather than numbers.  Your example needs to recognize things like `1_1_1__` as a single number with no gaps.

Comment: This is not related to a programming language, it is about data formatting and presentation. It needs to distinguish digits from text or tokens representing other things, this was my _minimal reproducible example_.